# Linux behaves strangely

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04, troubleshooting

Sometimes when I'm doing something which is not much stressing for my PC.
Everything stops and I can only move mouse.
Even music stops which is in background after short moment.

Do you know what can it be ?

Comment: Which OS are you using (Linux is to general. Ubuntu? Debian? SuSE? ...? Which version?). Have you tries SSHing into the machine from another machine?

Comment: Can you hit ctrl+alt+F1 to get into a terminal? Does it let you log in there and type commands while it is still stalled?  What kind and version of linux are you using? What kind of computer do you have? How new is it? and How much memory do you have?

Comment: Can you switch into terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6] when it happens?
Did you look for dmesg? /var/log/messages? /var/log/syslog? What graphical card, driver version, X version do yo have installed?

Comment: "Linux behaves strangely"... this is normal.

Answer (score 1):

These are some of the solutions other people used in other forums

- Try using another Web browser , in many other forums people say it crashes due to Firefox activities
- Try swapping , Instructions --->   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq
- **Try this and tell me if it works**

> *Try disabling "Cool n' Quiet" in your Bios or do the following:*
>
> ***Open a Termina, then***
>
> **1.**
>
> ```
> sudo su
>
> cp /etc/init.d/powernowd /etc/init.d/powernowd.bak
>
> gedit /etc/init.d/powernowd
> ```
>
> **2.** ***Just after the line***
>
> ```
> #! /bin/sh
> ```
>
> ***insert the following:***
>
> ```
> exit 0
> ```
>
> **3.** ***Save the file and restart.***